# Is it possible to change the unit in the column "Print Size" to millimeters in XnViewMP?

Tags: xnview

I often use this column to verify the size of my projects. I create all my projects in the millimeter unit. XNView shows centimeters.

Can it be changed to millimeters?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be implemented in 0.97.2

Source: https://www.xnview.com/mantisbt/view.php?id=1888